# Using ngControl caused error: No provider for ControlContainer

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use ngControl for the first time in my app:

```
<md-input placeholder="Amount" value="0" ngControl="ammount" required></md-input>
```

Added the following in my component:

```
import { FORM_PROVIDERS,FORM_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/common';

..

directives: [MD_INPUT_DIRECTIVES,
    FORM_DIRECTIVES,
    ],
    providers: [FORM_PROVIDERS],
```

and I get this error:

```
browser_adapter.ts:78 EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Template parse errors:
No provider for ControlContainer ("

[ERROR ->]<md-input placeholder="Amount" value="0" ngControl="ammount" required></md-input>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think that you forgot to wrap the `md-input` component in `form` tag, otherwise `ngControl` won't work:

```
<form>
   ...
   <md-input placeholder="Amount" value="0" ngControl="ammount" required></md-input>
   ...
</form>
```

> This directive can only be used as a child of NgForm or NgFormModel.

Answer (score 1):

To fix that, you have 2 options:
A. in main.ts:

```
import {FORM_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/common';

// other code here

bootstrap(AppCmp, [
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy }),
  FORM_PROVIDERS
]);
```

B. in your component that uses the form:

```
import {FORM_PROVIDERS, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
@Component({
  providers: [FORM_PROVIDERS],
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
```

Taken from these same issues on github

- https://github.com/mgechev/angular2-seed/issues/399
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6374

May help you.