# Using the latest builds of Angular 2 gives me the following error: "No provider for NgControl: in NgModule DynamicModule"

Tags: angular

I recently switched to using the latest builds of **Angular 2** and my app does not start because of the following error:

```
zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error: Provider parse errors:
    No provider for NgControl: in NgModule DynamicModule
        at new BaseException (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/facade/exceptions.js:27:23)
        at NgModuleProviderAnalyzer.parse (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/provider_analyzer.js:291:19)
        at NgModuleCompiler.compile (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/ng_module_compiler.js:57:24)
        at RuntimeCompiler._compileModule (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:121:56)
        at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:74:36)
        at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:50:21)
        at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/core/src/application_ref.js:361:25)
        at Object.bootstrap (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.js:73:10)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:8080/main.js:23:28)
        at eval (http://localhost:8080/main.js:46:4)
    Evaluating http://localhost:8080/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:8080/main.js
        at new BaseException (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/facade/exceptions.js:27:23)
        at NgModuleProviderAnalyzer.parse (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/provider_analyzer.js:291:19)
        at NgModuleCompiler.compile (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/ng_module_compiler.js:57:24)
        at RuntimeCompiler._compileModule (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:121:56)
        at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:74:36)
        at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/compiler/src/runtime_compiler.js:50:21)
        at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/core/src/application_ref.js:361:25)
        at Object.bootstrap (http://localhost:8080/vendor/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/index.js:73:10)
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:8080/main.js:23:28)
        at eval (http://localhost:8080/main.js:46:4)
    Evaluating http://localhost:8080/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:8080/main.js
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:538:32)
    at resolvePromise (http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:523:18)
    at http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:571:18
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
    at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:474:36)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:8080/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:426:22)
```

Can anyone please help?

**edit**:

Here is my `main.ts`:

```
import {bootstrap} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
import {enableProdMode} from "@angular/core";
import {Title} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import {provideRouter} from "@angular/router";
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from "@angular/common";
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, RequestOptions} from "@angular/http";
import {
  TRANSLATE_PROVIDERS,
  TranslateService,
  TranslateLoader,
  TranslateStaticLoader
} from "ng2-translate/ng2-translate";
import {AppComponent} from "./app/app.component";
import {SessionService} from "./app/session/session.service";
import {UserAccountService} from "./app/useraccount/useraccount.service";
import {ApplicationRequestOptions} from "./app/session/session.utils";
import {StylingService} from "./app/shared/services/styling.service";
import {AppRoutes} from "./app/routes/app.routes";
import {environment} from "./app/environment";
import {FormBuilder, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES} from "@angular/forms";
import {PasswordValidationService} from "./app/shared/services/password-validation.service";
import {validatePassword} from "./app/shared/validators/password.validator";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import {AuthenticatedHttpClient} from "./app/shared/services/authenticated-http-client.service";

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  provideRouter(AppRoutes),
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  TRANSLATE_PROVIDERS,
  Title,
  FormBuilder,
  REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES,
  SessionService,
  UserAccountService,
  AuthenticatedHttpClient,
  StylingService,
  TranslateService,
  PasswordValidationService,
  {provide: RequestOptions, useClass: ApplicationRequestOptions},
  {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
  {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: (http:Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'assets/i18n', '.json'), deps: [Http]
  }
]);
```

**edit 2**: My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "bignibou-client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "git+https://github.com/angular/common-builds.git#master",
    "@angular/compiler": "git+https://github.com/angular/compiler-builds.git#master",
    "@angular/core": "git+https://github.com/angular/core-builds.git#master",
    "@angular/forms": "git+https://github.com/angular/forms-builds.git#master",
    "@angular/http": "git+https://github.com/angular/http-builds.git#master",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "git+https://github.com/angular/platform-browser-builds.git#master",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "git+https://github.com/angular/platform-browser-dynamic-builds.git#master",
    "@angular/router": "git+https://github.com/angular/router-builds.git#master",
    "angular2-moment": "^0.8.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "moment": "^2.13.0",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.0.23",
    "ng2-translate": "^2.2.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.10",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.20",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8",
    "protractor": "3.3.0",
    "ts-node": "0.5.5",
    "tslint": "3.11.0",
    "typescript": "1.8.10",
    "typings": "0.8.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37284763/using-ngcontrol-caused-error-no-provider-for-controlcontainer

Comment: I believe it is a different issue. Nothing to to with the `forms` module. Rather with the `platform-browser-dynamic` module.

Comment: See https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10476

Answer (score 4):

You might want to migrate to RC5. The new ngModule really helps to organize imports and greatly simplifies bootsraping your application.

This guide helped me a lot with understanding the motivation of the new changes: [Angular RC5: NgModules, Lazy Loading and AoT compilation](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/08/angular-2-rc5-ngmodules-lazy-loading.html)

There is also a neat guide on angular's site to migrate to RC5 [RC4 to RC5 Migration](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html)

You will have to remove the `REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES` and all similar imports and simply import their corresponding Module in your app.module.ts

Example:

main.ts:

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule }              from './app.module';

enableProdMode();
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule); //just in time compilation
```

app.routes.ts

```
import {Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './Dashboard/dashboard.component';;
import { CanDeactivateGuard } from './Services/canDeactivateGuard.service';

export const appRoutes : Routes= [
    {path:'', redirectTo:'home', pathMatch:"full"},
    {path:'home', component: DashboardComponent}
];

export const routingProviders: any[]=[
    CanDeactivateGuard
];
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { appRoutes, routingProviders } from './app.routes';
import { AppComponent }   from './app.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './Dashboard/dashboard.component';
import {CookieService} from 'angular2-cookie/core';

import { InputFilterService } from './Services/inputFilter.service';
import { SessionService } from './Services/session.service';
import { CanDeactivateGuard } from './Services/canDeactivateGuard.service';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent, 
        DashboardComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
    providers:[
        CookieService,
        InputFilterService,
        SessionService,
       routingProviders
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Using this pattern you can forget about the directives and providers arrays in your component definitions as long as they are part of the same module and are correctly included there. For example: You can forget about handling  `ROUTER_DIRECTIVES` and such since they are already bundled as part of other modules like the `Router Module`, which is imported to your `App Module`. In my opinion this is a major feature because it adds proper encapsulation and provides a scheme to develop a better architecture for your application. 
I hope you find this helpful. Good luck

Comment: Be great if you posted your app.module.ts as an example.

Comment: There you go mate. @jeff

Answer (score 2):

The component being rendered needs to have REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES loaded as a directive. ie:

```
import {NgForm, FORM_DIRECTIVES, REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  directives: [
    FORM_DIRECTIVES,
    REACTIVE_FORM_DIRECTIVES,
    NgForm
 ]
})
export class MyComponent {
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the new forms module

```
import { disableDeprecatedForms, provideForms }     from '@angular/forms';
import { HelloComponent }                           from './hello.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    disableDeprecatedForms(),
    provideForms(),
    ...
```

Comment: `disableDeprecatedForms` and `provideForms` seem to be deprecated as of the latest builds.

Comment: I missed that you use nightly builds from GitHub. Haven't tried myself.

Comment: They have introduced a great deal of changes: `@NgModule` seems to be mandatory now. I am trying to get it to work and I will publish here if I do manage to get something working.