# Angular2 Material input field shows No Provider for Control

Tags: angular

I am developing one Angular2 application. I created one component. I used input field for typing the name. But I am getting the following error. "No Provider for Ng control". I am not getting what is the issue here?

Comment: Add the exact error description in your question. And some details about your code what you have tried so far.

Comment: No form tag? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37285334/2918518)

Comment: Make sure to add the correct imports in app.module.ts  import {MdInputModule} from '@angular/material';

Comment: have you imported formsModule and BrowserModule. ?

Comment: Was just going to say what @SHIVAMJINDAL said. You have to import the reactive forms module.